Is there a way to format a Luxon Datetime to the hundredth of a second?
I have a Duration in Luxon that includes milliseconds that I need to be able to show in different levels of precision the same way that that Excel date formats can show fractional number portions (whole numbers, tenths, hundredths, or thousandths). Is there a way to use the built in duration formatting to do this? In my typescript react app, I tried the following things and they don't seem correct:
Duration.fromMillis(546123).toFormat("m:ss") // yields "9:06" but I expect 9:07
Duration.fromMillis(546123).toFormat("m:ss.S") // yields "9:06.599" but I expect 9:06.6
Duration.fromMillis(546123).toFormat("m:ss.SS") // yields "9:06.599" but I expect 9:06.60
Duration.fromMillis(546123).toFormat("m:ss.SSS") // yields "9:06.599" as expected
Is there a different format to use to properly show fractional seconds and correctly round numbers up/down? If Luxon can't do it natively, is there some other library that can work with Luxon to do the formatting correctly?
